# WFS-T add point to postGIS table via Openlayers 3 / geoserver

Tags: postgis, openlayers-3, geoserver

I have a simple web mapping app that tries to add points to a map via a WFS-T layer with openlayers 3. For the backend I'm using geoserver v2.8.0 and a postGIS database. I've been following the great tutorial from [dbauszus](http://wordpress-dbauszus.rhcloud.com/wfs-t-with-openlayers-3-5/) and I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30440460/openlayers-3-wfs-t-post-feature-to-postgis-via-geoserver) question on stack overflow, which is pointing me into the right direction but I m still missing some point.
It's kind of strange because when i add a point to the map it get's transferred into the postGIS db, a ID is set and the attribute "test" is set but the geometry column is empty. I'm assuming something with my transferred xml is not right but i can't figure out what.

Ahh don't know if it helps but CORS is enabled on my geoserver and i'm running the html site on a local web server.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();
var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
    featureNS: 'vm',
    featurePrefix:'vm',
    featureType: 'GT_Projects',
    srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
});

var transactWFS = function(p,f) {
    switch(p) {
    case 'insert':
        node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([f],null,null,formatGML);
        console.log(node);
        break;
    case 'update':
        node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null,[f],null,formatGML);
        break;
    case 'delete':
        node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null,null,[f],formatGML);
        break;
    }
    s = new XMLSerializer();
    str = s.serializeToString(node);
    console.log(str);
    $.ajax('http://geoserver-vmarquar.rhcloud.com:80/wfs',{
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'text/xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        processData: false,
        data: str
        }).done();
    }

$('.btnMenu').on('click', function(event) {
$('.btnMenu').removeClass('orange');
$(this).addClass('orange');
map.removeInteraction(interaction);
select.getFeatures().clear();
map.removeInteraction(select);
switch($(this).attr('id')) {
// DRAW POINT
case 'btnDrawPoint':
    interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        type: 'Point',
        source: layerVector.getSource()
    });
    map.addInteraction(interaction);
    interaction.on('drawend', function(e) {
        var feature = e.feature;
        feature.set('name', "test");
        // feature.set('geom', feature.getGeometry());
        transactWFS('insert',feature);

    });
    break;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the log file says?

Comment: This is the raw xml request followed by a bunch of Unicode replacement signs � � � : 2016-03-13 09:26:51,142 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Raw XML request: <Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Insert><GT_Projects xmlns="vm"><geometry><Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><pos>-1379535.4864908587 7436010.171961442</pos></Point></geometry><name>test</name></GT_Projects></Insert></Transaction>��  Does that help?

Comment: Please let me know if you need a more detailed log so I can see if I can upload it somewhere.

Comment: Is the name of the column 'geom'? In what projection is that geometry column in Postgis?

Comment: Yes name is geom and projection should be EPSG:3857 which is the same as my open layers 3 map.