# Editing shapefile in a webapp

Tags: maps, gis, qgis

I need to develop a web application  to make users edit a shapefile in the browser.
Main idea would be to load a shapefile with his layers, and then let users create lines, polylines and so, saving that data to the shapefile.
An improvememt would be to save data to db.

I searched on the Internet but I can't find a opensource solution.
I took a look at lizmap and qgis server but It seems there Is not the possibility to insert vectorial items or edit the Ones already present.

Can someone help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can be achieved by using [GeoServer](https://geoserver.org) and a WFS-T client such as [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org). See for example [this tutorial](http://geo.ifip.tuwien.ac.at/imak/2009/stack_workshop/doc/wfs_editor/wfst.html) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30440460/openlayers-3-wfs-t-post-feature-to-postgis-via-geoserver) for examples.